# Reusing Visual Studio's Syntax Editor control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I know there are a lot of questions regarding reusable syntax editors, it's something that I've researched a lot in the past.

I am currently researching ICSharpCode's TextEditor control, but when I looked for the control to add to the WinForms toolbox, I found something quite interesting...

[image]

Do Microsoft use [Actipro's Syntax Editor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/wpf/syntaxeditor) control for WPF in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't think, that EULA will allow you to re-use this editor, even if VS uses itself.

Comment: Visual Studio uses many open source components as well as commercial ones. What's the point of this question?

Comment: @LexLi the point is that if Visual Studio used Actipro's editor I might be inclined to invest in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Actipro syntax editor is a component of Blend.

I thought Microsoft acquired Blend from a 3rd party software company along with other products in the Expression suite, but after searching online I can't find any evidence of this. Maybe I imagined it..

Comment: I remember when WPF was first introduced, I was watching a video on MSDN channel 9 and Microsoft were developing Blend as part of their WPF strategy. I think the entire expression framework is developed by Microsoft

Comment: That is strange, I'm sure I can remember Expression being developed by another company and being bought by Microsoft. I must be thinking of something else.